# QWebView won't load any page

Tags: qt, qwebview, qwebkit

When I've tried to load a page using `QWebView`, all I've gotten is a blank window.
It also gives me this error :

LEAK: 3 RenderObject
LEAK: 1 Page
LEAK: 1 Frame
LEAK: 1 SubresourceLoader
LEAK: 1 CachedResource
LEAK: 4 WebCoreNode

Here is my code:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QtWebKit>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QUrl>
#include <QtNetwork>
#include "FenPrincipale.h"

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc,argv);

    QWebView *view = new QWebView;
        view->load(QUrl("http://qt.nokia.com/"));
        view->show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Regular browsers also show a "blank window" if you go to http://qt.nokia.com/. This URL is no longer valid.

Try replacing it with http://www.qt.io/.